# About weight generator of quadratic lattices

Tags: nt.number-theory, lattices, quadratic-forms

I get stuck on Example 93:5 in O'Meara's book "Introduction to quadratic forms", where it is explained a method of find a weight generator of a quadratic lattice.

In this question I assume familarity with notions and facts in O'Meara's book (at least those in $\S$93). Here a quadratic lattice L in a (nonsingular quadratic space V) is given over a dyadic local field F.  Then it is asserted the following:

Take $b_0\in Q(L)$ of largest (absolute) value such that $ord(a)+ord(b_0)$ is odd, where $a\in Q(L)$ is a norm generator. If $b_0\mathfrak{o}_F\subseteq 2\mathfrak{s}(L)$ or $b_0$ does not exist, then the weight $\mathfrak{w}(L)$ is equal to $2\mathfrak{s}(L)$. Otherwise, $\mathfrak{w}(L)$ is $b_0\mathfrak{o}_F$.

I have difficulty in proving these two statements, because I think valuations of elements in the ideal $\mathfrak{m}L$ (the largest one in $\mathfrak{g}L$) may not be realizable as valuations of elements from $Q(L)$. (So I don't know how to use the fact that $ord(a)+ord(\mathfrak{m}L)$ is even.)

Maybe the question is kind of too specialized. But I hope someone can provide some details or hints.
Many thanks in advance.